# align a html form with css issue

Tags: html, css, input, css-float, textarea

I have a form inside a `#main` div, I want all the label to be on the left, and all the input area to be on the right.

So i have these CSS:

```
.right{
    float:right;
}

#main{
    width:80%;
}

textarea{
    resize:none; 
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <form name="form1">
    <div>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="right">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="description">About you</label>
        <textarea name="description" class="right"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="location">Location</label>
        <input type="text" name="location" class="right">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

but the textarea doesn't want to go on the right, plus the inputs are going through the divs

here a jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/malamine_kebe/ZE7tp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include a `float:right` to the textarea.

Updated approach here: http://jsfiddle.net/nbrLJ/

Also include a `clear:both` to the div's.

Tip - you can target the form elements without a new class name, for example:

```
div.row input,
div.row textarea {
    float:right;
}
```

Adding a width to the parent container will also help:

```
#main {
    width:300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert but I think you need to clear your floats

```
.clearfix {
 clear: both
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZE7tp/2/

Answer (score 0):

Your inputs are running into each other. Notice they are pushing each other to the left. Set margins to give it some breathing room.

```
div {
    margin: 3em 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZE7tp/3/